# google maps api 3 simultaneously panning and zooming

Tags: maps, zooming, panning

I've made code to pan simultaneously with 2 google maps windows (api 3 version). I would like also be able to zoom simultaneously. I've made it work in api2 but I don't get it to work in ap3-version of google maps. Has anyone suggestions? Thanks in advance

[example working of current code](http://www.websites-maken.nl/tmp/test.html)

```
var map;
var map2;
function load(x,y) {

var myOptions = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

var myOptions2 = {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
}
map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), myOptions2);

        var map_moving = 0;
        var map2_moving = 0;

        var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();  

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {


                            map2_moving = true;
            if (map_moving == false) {
                map2.setCenter(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
                                    infowindow.setContent('Zoom: ' + zoomLevel);
            }
                            map_moving = false;
                            map2_moving = true;
});


  google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                        map_moving = true;
            if (map2_moving == false) {
                        map.setCenter(map2.getCenter(), map2.getZoom());
                                    infowindow.setContent('Zoom: ' + zoomLevel);
            }
                            map_moving = true;
                            map2_moving = false;

});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});
}
  //]]>
```

Greetings
Bas